# In What Order are Answers Loaded?

Tags: discussion, answers, page-load

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Response order (read: I like rep points)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95270/response-order-read-i-like-rep-points)

If you refresh a question whose answers have equal votes, the answers will appear in a different order.

Is this order explicitly randomly generated?  Or does it just have to do with some sort of race condition in loading the page?

Comment: This _has_ to be a dupe, from like thirty times over

Answer (score 1):

It's deliberately random to prevent voting bias.

Comment: My voting bias is to upvote a randomly-chosen answer.